# Pandas / Check if a string is in a column

Tags: pandas

I am using this syntax to check if a string is inside the column "TRI" of my dataframe :

```
if myWord[i] in df.TRI:
```

And it doesn't work (although it worked with numerical value in other case)

What could be the reason ?

Comment: The appropriate formula is `df["TRI"].str.contains(myWord[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution :

```
if myWord[i] in df["TRI"].unique():
```